How to properly implement the HashMap data structure class with seperate chaining using linked lists in JavaScript?
So i tried implementing the HashMap data structure in JavaScript and i'm not really sure whether it's the proper way of implementing it. If maybe you could give a better implementation or just improve my code, it'd be of great help.
Here is my implementation of the HashMap data structure with seperate chaining:
const Node = require('../../linear_data_structures/Node/Node_6');
const LinkedList = require('../../linear_data_structures/LinkedList/SinglyLinkedList/LinkedList_7');

class HashMap {
    constructor(size = 1) {
        this.hashmap = new Array(size)
                       .fill(null)
                       .map(() => new LinkedList());
    }

    hash(key) {
        let hashCode = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
            hashCode += key.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        return hashCode % this.hashmap.length;
    }

    assign(key, value) {
        const arrayIndex = this.hash(key);
        const linkedList = this.hashmap[arrayIndex];
        
        if (!linkedList.head) {
            linkedList.addToHead({ key, value });
            return;
        }

        let current = linkedList.head;

        while (current) {
            if (current.data.key === key) {
                current.data = { key, value };
                break;
            }

            if (current.getNextNode() === null) {
                const lastNode = new Node({ key, value });
                current.setNextNode(lastNode);
                break;
            }

            current = current.getNextNode();
        }
    }

    retrieve(key) {
        const arrayIndex = this.hash(key);
        let current = this.hashmap[arrayIndex].head;

        while (current) {
            if (current.data.key === key) {
                return current.data.value;
            }

            current = current.getNextNode();
        }

        return null;
    }

    delete(key) {
        const arrayIndex = this.hash(key);
        let linkedList = this.hashmap[arrayIndex];
        let current = linkedList.head;
        let prev;

        while (current) {
            if (current.data.key === key) {
                if (prev) {
                    prev.setNextNode(current.getNextNode());
                } else {
                    linkedList.head = current.getNextNode();
                }
                return current.data.value;
            }
            prev = current;
            current = current.getNextNode();
        }
        return null;
    }

    printListByKey(key) {
        const arrayIndex = this.hash(key);
        let current = this.hashmap[arrayIndex].head;
        const output = [];

        while (current) {
            output.push(current.data.value);
            current = current.getNextNode();
        }

        console.log('<head> ' + output.join(' --> ') + ' <tail>');
    }
}

module.exports = HashMap;


Here is the Node class I used for the HashMap.
class Node {
  constructor(data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.next = null;
  }
  
  setNextNode(data) {
    if (data instanceof Node || data === null) {
      this.next = data;
    } else {
      throw new Error("Expected Node instance or null");
    }
  }
  
  getNextNode() {
    return this.next;
  }
}

module.exports = Node;

and, Here is the Singly Linked List class I used for the HashMap
const Node = require('../../Node/Node_6');

class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
  }
  
  addToHead(data) {
    const newHead = new Node(data);
    const currentHead = this.head;
    this.head = newHead;
    if (currentHead) {
      this.head.setNextNode(currentHead);
    }
  }
  
  addToTail(data) {
    const lastNode = this.head;
    if (!lastNode) {
      this.head = new Node(data);
    } else {
      let temp = this.head;
      while (temp.getNextNode() !== null) {
        temp = temp.getNextNode();
      }
      temp.setNextNode(new Node(data));
    }
  }
  
  removeHead() {
    const removedHead = this.head;
    if (!removedHead) {
      return;
    }
    this.head = removedHead.getNextNode()
    return removedHead.data;
  }
  
  removeTail() {
    const lastNode = this.head;
    if (!lastNode) {
      return;
    } else {
      let removedTail = this.head;
      let pred;
      while (removedTail.getNextNode() !== null) {
        pred = removedTail;
        removedTail = removedTail.getNextNode();
      }
      if (pred) {
        pred.setNextNode(null);
        return removedTail.data;
      } else {
        return this.removeHead();
      }
    }
  }
  
  removeByData(data) {
    let currentNode = this.head;
    let removedNode;
    
    if (currentNode.data === data) {
      return this.removeHead();
    }
    
    while (currentNode.getNextNode().data !== data) {
      currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
    }
    removedNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
    currentNode.setNextNode(removedNode.getNextNode());
    return removedNode.data;
  }
  
  printList() {
    let currentNode = this.head;
    let output = '<head> ';
    
    while (currentNode) {
      output += currentNode.data + ' ';
      currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
    }
    output += '<tail>';
    console.log(output);
  }
}

module.exports = LinkedList;


"If maybe you could give a better implementation or just improve my code": this is a question that is off-topic on this site. If there is a problem with your code, it could be made on-topic by focusing on that problem (how to reproduce it, what is expected, what you get instead, what you have debugged). If however there is no problem, but you look for a code review, then maybe consider posting on CodeReview, but then be sure it works as expected and that you follow their guidelines before posting.
